# how do i sum data pulled out of a sub-report in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am able to pull a field out of the sub report with 
shared numbervar sub1Total; 
but I need to add them up at the end of group. If I try and do a sum on the field in the main report I get an error that that field can not be used with sum.

Comment: What do you mean by "add them up at the end of group"? What group? What are you trying to sum? You should add more detail to the question.

Comment: Yes the subreport runs line for line with the main report. at the end of a group in the main report I need to do a sum. I can't do that in the subreport since it starts over on each line of the main report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add up the values passed back from the subreport by keeping track of them via a global variable in the main report.

```
//Initialize the variable in the Group Header of the main report
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar groupsub := 0;

//Update the variable in the Details section of the main report
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar groupsub;
shared numbervar subval;

groupsub := groupsub + subval;

//Print the accumulated group value in the Group Footer of the main report
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar groupsub;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: only works if the sum

groupsub := groupsub + subval;

is in **Details Section**